# Facebook C# SDK WP7 - Can't upload photo to Facebook

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm trying to upload a photo to facebook using the Facebook C# SDK with WP7.
Here's my code:

```
public void PostMessageWithImage(string statusMessage, Stream stream)
    {
        FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient(AccessToken);
        FacebookMediaStream mediaStream = new FacebookMediaStream
        {
            FileName = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().ToLongDateString(),
            ContentType = "image/jpeg",
        }.SetValue(stream);

        fb.PostCompleted += MessagePostCompleted;
        fb.PostAsync(this.id + "/photos", new
            {                    
                message = statusMessage, //already tried name and caption
                source = mediaStream
            });
    }
```

I keep getting this:

```
(OAuthException - #1) (#1) An unknown error occurred 
    at Facebook.FacebookClient.ProcessResponse(HttpHelper httpHelper, String responseString, Type resultType, Boolean containsEtag, IList`1 batchEtags)
    at Facebook.FacebookClient.<>c__DisplayClass4.<ApiAsync>b__1(Object o, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
```

This code was working fine four months ago, but now I just can't upload photos to Facebook. It only works when I use a url instead of a file. Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got same error.
that my code :

```
        dynamic argumentContent = new ExpandoObject();
        argumentContent.message = imageDesc;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(imageUrl))
            argumentContent.url = imageUrl;
        else
            argumentContent.source = new FacebookMediaObject
            {
                ContentType = "image/jpeg",
                FileName = FormatUploadPictureFileName()
            }.SetValue(imageBytes);

        FacebookClient fbClient = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
        fbClient.PostTaskAsync("me/photos", argumentContent);
        fbClient.PostCompleted += (postContent, Ex) =>
        {});
```

soluction:

if this image create with your code and format as stream. so you will got this error.
first you need save it as png/jpeg file to  isolate storage .
then read it and format to bytes[] array from local isolate storage . 
  you will found it's work.